# Why is it trying to send a char array instead of a string?

Tags: c++, class, function, types, arrays

My function declaration is
 `siteObject(std::string& url, std::string& get, std::string& post);`

So why is this `site("String 1", "String 2", "String 3")`; creating a mismatch type error. It says it wants a string reference and it's receiving a char array. If you need more detail just ask in the comments.

Comment: Long story short: C designers made string literaks type `char[]`; C++ designers made C++ compatible with C and gave every C++ programmer, including you, a whole bunch of annoyances, including this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there's an implicit call to the `std::string` constructor, which creates a temporary object.  You cannot take a non-const reference to a temporary (because it's meaningless to modify a temporary).

So, either modify your function to take `const` references, or by-value, or pass it non-temporary objects.

Comment: is this the only way to do it?

Comment: This will not work on compilers that are more standard's compliant than MSVC. Since you want to pass a temporary object as a non-const reference.

Comment: @Will03, you could as well write your procedure as `siteObject(const std::string & url , const std::string& get, etc).`

Comment: @Muggen:  If the strings are not changed in the function, that works.

Answer (score 3):

Your `siteObject` function:

```
siteObject(std::string& url, std::string& get, std::string& post);
```

takes non-const references to string objects, which cannot be bound to rvalues (or temporaries).

When you try to call the function with string literals, the compiler has to convert those arguments (which are `char*`) to something that matches the parameter types - that conversion results in a temporary `std::string` object.

You'll need to change your function to accept const references if you want to be able to bind them to temporaries:

```
siteObject(std::string const& url, std::string const& get, std::string const& post);
```

Or you could pass values instead of references:

```
siteObject(std::string url, std::string get, std::string post);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is:

```
std::string url("...");
std::string get("...");
std::string post("...");

siteObject(url, get, post);
```

This makes sense since the method signature implies that you get something back in the three strings (non-const references) and you may use those return values.

If that's not the intention and you have the ability to change the siteObject() method then you should do:

```
siteObject(std::string const & url, std::string const & get, std::string const & post);
```

and use your original call.

Comment: That wasn't answering the question??

Answer (score 1):

You need to either make your function accept `const std::string& str` or construct string instances to pass in, and not rely on the implicit conversion of char* to string objects.

Answer (score 0):

Strings entered in double quote characters are coming from the C heritage of C++ (they are called C string or NUL terminated string). They are implemented by the compiler as array of `char`. On the contrary, the `std::string` is a C++ class that aims to simplify manipulation of strings. It owns a C string (and can be created from one since it has a constructor that accept a `const char*`), and manage its memory.

Since there exists a construtor of `std::string` from `const char*` and that C string are compatible with that type, how come the compiler cannot call this function ? This is because the function is taking non-const reference to `std::string` objects. The constructor can't be used in this situation because the objects created would be temporaries, and you cannot get a non-const reference to a temporary object, as the called function may mutate it.

You can either create the `std::string` and pass them to the function:

```
std::string s1("String 1");
std::string s2("String 2");
std::string s3("String 3");
site(s1, s2, s3);
```

Or you can change the prototype of the `site` function to accept const reference. This is only possible if the function does not mutate the objects and you have access to the code:

```
// Declaration
void site(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string s3);

// Usage
site("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");
```